# Altium connection lines do not show the shortest connection

Tags: altium, trace

The connections are between a processor and a DDR chip. The problem is that Altium only shows pad to pad connection line not the shortest (eg not via to via or via to pad). The strange thing is when I start routing, still do not show actively the closest track segment. I checked the topology rules and "From to editor" property. Everything is normal. I couldn't figure it out. I can route those tracks anyway. But this is really annoying.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried altium discord support?

Comment: Try using the CTRL-H function.. It will highlight all connected copper for you, makes it much easier to visually see where stuff is going.     (Press & hold CTRL-H, and then click on your copper pad).    I don't believe there is a way to make the rats nest  connections connect 'closest to closest'.  They do what they do....

Comment: I have seen this same issue. @KyleB there are settings that supposedly tell the rats nest to connect "closest to closest", "star pattern", "daisy chain", etc. It just doesn't seem to work properly.